# Разрешение зависимостей

Tags: haskell

Пытаюсь собрать тестовую програму с текстовым интерфейсом. В качестве  библиотеки изпользую [Vty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty)

Код:

```
 import Graphics.Vty.Widgets.All
 import qualified Data.Text as T

 main :: IO ()
 main = do
 e <- editWidget
 ui <- centered e

 fg <- newFocusGroup
 addToFocusGroup fg e

 c <- newCollection
 addToCollection c ui fg

 e `onActivate` \this -> 
             getEditText this >>= (error. ("You entered: " ++))

 runUi c defaultContext
```

После запуска `stack build` получаю следующее сообщение:

```
 $ stack build
 While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
  vty-ui: needed (-any), couldn't resolve its dependencies
needed for package: LearnHaskell-0.1.0.0

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
  QuickCheck: needed (>=2.4 && <2.8), 2.8.1 found (latest version available)
needed for package: vty-ui-1.9
```

Если я всё правильно понимаю, то для пакета vty-ui-1.9 нужен модуль QuickCheck (< 2.8), но на данный момент доступен модуль 2.8.1

```
 QuickCheck: needed (>=2.4 && <2.8), 2.8.1 found (latest version   available)
 needed for package: vty-ui-1.9
```

Каким образом можно разрешить данный конфликт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Каким образом можно разрешить данный конфликт?

возможно, поможет [установка конкретной версии пакета](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5140957/4827341):

```
cabal install QuickCheck-2.8
```